# Is there a way to locate a Gmail conversation by the old HTML link after migrating to G Suite?

Tags: gmail, google-sheets, migration, google-workspace-for-business

We have some links to specific emails in some of our Sheets, but these mails got a new unique ID after the data migration to G Suite, so these links are not pointing anywhere now.

Is there any way to update the sheet references, or to find the mail based on the old link?

An example of this:

```
=HYPERLINK("https://mail.google.com/mail/#inbox/15aad2350b5ca132", "something")
```

As I understand, the `15aad2350b5ca132` part of the URL is a permanent number associated with a certain thread in Gmail. After moving everything to G Suite however, these numbers have changed, so it doesn't work any longer. These are just internal links to help our own work, and there are several thousands of them, and I'd like to know if there is any other way to update these URLs other than manually changing them one by one.